# Javascript - unity-styled number adjuster

Tags: javascript

I'm working on having a number input that lets the user adjust the value by clicking and holding the mouse button and moving the cursor left and right (without a slider and there is no minimum or maximum). This is similar to how unity's editor number adjuster works: https://youtu.be/uY9PAcNMu8s?t=907

My current problem is getting it to work if there are multiple elements with this behavior. One method in attempting to distinguish which one the user is trying to adjust the values with the mouse cursor is by making use of `id` and `class`es. Here is the source code (copy the entire thing, paste it in an empty HTML file, and open that with a browser):

```
<input type="number" id="Testing1" value="0"><span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="MouseDragSpace1"><table><tr><td style="width:1000; height:100; border-width:1px; border: 1px solid black;"></td></tr></table></span><br><br>
<input type="number" id="Testing2" value="0"><span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="MouseDragSpace2"><table><tr><td style="width:1000; height:100; border-width:1px; border: 1px solid black;"></td></tr></table></span><br><br>


<span id="MousePos"></span>
<span id="DeltaDrag"></span>
<span id="IncrementDecrement"></span>
<script>
    //Initialize some variables
        DragOriginX = 0
        DragOriginY = 0
        WhichElement = ""
        ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClickHoldChangeNumber")
    window.onload=function(){
        SourcePosition = 0
        MouseState = ""
        let thing = ""
        //ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClickHoldChangeNumber")
        //addEventListener only applies to individual elements, so we need to loop to place an event listener to each class.
            let Index = 0
            while (Index < ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses.length) {
                thing = ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id
                ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].addEventListener('mousedown', function(){PlaceDragOriginPos(ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id)})
                Index++
            }
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', ExitPlaceDragOriginPos);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);
        
    }
    function logKey(e) {
        if (MouseState != "PressedDown") {
            DragOriginX = e.clientX
            DragOriginY = e.clientY
        }
        document.getElementById("MousePos").innerHTML = "Mouse position: (" + DragOriginX.toString(10) + ", " + DragOriginY.toString(10) + ")<br>"
        document.getElementById("DeltaDrag").innerHTML = "Delta from mouse position: (" + (e.clientX - DragOriginX).toString(10) + ", " + (e.clientY - DragOriginY).toString(10) + ")<br>"
        if (MouseState == "PressedDown") {
            SubFunctionVariable = [e.clientX, e.clientY]
            MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease()
        }
    }
    function MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease() {
        document.getElementById("Testing1").value = (SourcePosition + (SubFunctionVariable[0] - DragOriginX)).toString(10)
    }
    function PlaceDragOriginPos(ElementID) {
        MouseState = "PressedDown"
    }
    function ExitPlaceDragOriginPos() {
        SourcePosition = parseInt(document.getElementById("Testing1").value)
        
        MouseState = "Released"
    }
</script>
```

The page loading works fine, but when I click-hold on those rectangular boxes to adjust the value it errors out (`Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`), even though I defined them using a global scope. I do not know why it is undefined when the object is placed as a global variable, and is set during a page load.

As a side note, does anyone know what this UI called?

Answer (score 0):

That is because Index = 2 after your window.onload has excecuted the while loop The eventhandler is attached to the element you try to find so you can use 'this'

```
ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    //PlaceDragOriginPos(ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id);
    PlaceDragOriginPos(this.id);
});
```

**EDIT:**
My new suggestion has replaced input ids with a class (ChangeNumber) and has a single eventhandler attached to document.body (event delegation: eg. https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

You know which element has been clicked by examining the event.target and takes action for input.ChangeNumber only

Set SourcePosition, DragOriginX and DragOriginY has been moved to mousedown and logKey is checking that the left button is down which eliminates the need for MouseState, MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease and ExitPlaceDragOriginPos

This solution do not require any change to the script when you add more 'ChangeNumber's

```
<h1 style="">Unity-styled number adjuster</h1>
<p>Press and hold down the left mouse button over &ldquo;Value 1/2/3&rdquo; and move your mouse left or right to adjust the value in the input boxes</p>
<span>Value 1:</span> <input type="number" class="ChangeNumber" value="0"><br>
<span>Value 2:</span> <input type="number" class="ChangeNumber" value="0"><br>
<span>Value 3:</span> <input type="number" class="ChangeNumber" value="0"><br>
<span id="MousePos"></span>
<span id="DeltaDrag"></span>
<span id="IncrementDecrement"></span>
<span id="SourcePosition"></span>
<script>
    DragOriginX = 0;
    DragOriginY = 0;
    SourcePosition = 0;
    WhichElement = null;
    window.onload=function(){
        // Delegate a single event handler to handle all ChangeNumber
        document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            WhichElement = e.target.closest('.ChangeNumber');
            if (WhichElement) { // Clicked on a input.ChangeNumber?
                SourcePosition = parseInt(WhichElement.value);
                DragOriginX = e.clientX;
                DragOriginY = e.clientY;
            }
        });
        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);        
    }
    function logKey(e) {
        document.getElementById("MousePos").innerHTML = "Mouse position: (" + DragOriginX.toString(10) + ", " + DragOriginY.toString(10) + ")<br>"
        document.getElementById("DeltaDrag").innerHTML = "Delta from mouse position: (" + (e.clientX - DragOriginX).toString(10) + ", " + (e.clientY - DragOriginY).toString(10) + ")<br>"
        if (e.buttons == 1 && WhichElement) { // 1: Left Mouse Button
            WhichElement.value = (SourcePosition + (e.clientX - DragOriginX)).toString(10)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wait what? Didn't that loop condition will not to execute if Index is 2 or higher? I use a "Less than" operator, not "Less than or equal to".

Comment: Last item has Index 1, Index++ makes Index==2, while breaks because it is not < 2

Comment: The error is triggered on mousedown because ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[2] does not exist and translates to undefined, ie. undefined.id does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Better solution: `bind`

```
<input type="number" id="Testing1" value="0"><span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="MouseDragSpace1"><table><tr><td style="width:1000; height:100; border-width:1px; border: 1px solid black;"></td></tr></table></span><br><br>
<input type="number" id="Testing2" value="0"><span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="MouseDragSpace2"><table><tr><td style="width:1000; height:100; border-width:1px; border: 1px solid black;"></td></tr></table></span><br><br>


<span id="MousePos"></span>
<span id="DeltaDrag"></span>
<span id="IncrementDecrement"></span>
<span id="SourcePosition"></span>
<script>
    //Initialize some variables
        DragOriginX = 0
        DragOriginY = 0
        WhichElement = ""
        ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClickHoldChangeNumber")
    window.onload=function(){
        SourcePosition = 0
        MouseState = ""
        let thing = ""
        //ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClickHoldChangeNumber")
        //addEventListener only applies to individual elements, so we need to loop to place an event listener to each class.
            let Index = 0
            while (Index < ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses.length) {
                thing = ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id
                ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].addEventListener('mousedown', PlaceDragOriginPos.bind(event, ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id))
                Index++
            }
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', ExitPlaceDragOriginPos);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);
        
    }
    function logKey(e) {
        if (MouseState != "PressedDown") {
            DragOriginX = e.clientX
            DragOriginY = e.clientY
        }
        document.getElementById("MousePos").innerHTML = "Mouse position: (" + DragOriginX.toString(10) + ", " + DragOriginY.toString(10) + ")<br>"
        document.getElementById("DeltaDrag").innerHTML = "Delta from mouse position: (" + (e.clientX - DragOriginX).toString(10) + ", " + (e.clientY - DragOriginY).toString(10) + ")<br>"
        if (MouseState == "PressedDown") {
            SubFunctionVariable = [e.clientX, e.clientY]
            MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease()
        }
    }
    function MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease() {
        if (WhichElement == "MouseDragSpace1") {
            document.getElementById("Testing1").value = (SourcePosition + (SubFunctionVariable[0] - DragOriginX)).toString(10)
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Testing2").value = (SourcePosition + (SubFunctionVariable[0] - DragOriginX)).toString(10)
        }
    }
    function PlaceDragOriginPos(ElementID) {
        WhichElement = ElementID
        MouseState = "PressedDown"
        //SourcePosition = parseInt(document.getElementById(WhichElement).value)
        if (WhichElement == "MouseDragSpace1") {
            SourcePosition = parseInt(document.getElementById("Testing1").value)
        } else {
            SourcePosition = parseInt(document.getElementById("Testing2").value)
        }
    }
    function ExitPlaceDragOriginPos() {
        //SourcePosition = parseInt(document.getElementById("Testing1").value)
        
        MouseState = "Released"
    }
</script>
```

Still a WIP, I wanted to make it so you don't need to edit the code when you wanted to add more number input using this JS system.

Comment: bind creates a new function, ie. number of functions = number of number inputs when a single function is sufficient
He wants to find which input is clicked and that is the input the handler is attached to, ie. 'this'

Comment: .. and 'you don't need to edit the code when you wanted to add more number input'

Answer (score 0):

Newer update and better revision, this time, actually fixed the selection issue from messing up the system (it causes it to ignore the first mouseup event, which means it remains in this “drag” state even when the user let go of the left mouse button, until the user presses and releases the button). Made it so you can add more html tags with this behavior without the need to edit the JS code to include those new HTML inputs:

```
<h1 style="">Unity-styled number adjuster</h1>

<p>Press and hold down the left mouse button over &ldquo;Value 1/2/3&rdquo; and move your mouse left or right to adjust the value in the input boxes</p>

<span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="NumbInput_Testing1">Value 1:</span> <input type="number" id="Testing1" value="0"><br>
<span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="NumbInput_Testing2">Value 2:</span> <input type="number" id="Testing2" value="0"><br>
<span class="ClickHoldChangeNumber" id="NumbInput_Testing3">Value 3:</span> <input type="number" id="Testing3" value="0"><br>

<span id="MousePos"></span>
<span id="DeltaDrag"></span>
<span id="IncrementDecrement"></span>
<span id="SourcePosition"></span>
<script>
//Initialize some variables
        MouseDragOriginX = 0
        MouseDragOriginY = 0
        WhichElement = ""
        ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClickHoldChangeNumber")
//Attach event listeners to elements
    window.onload=function(){
        SourcePosition = 0
        MouseState = ""
        let thing = ""
        //addEventListener only applies to individual elements, so we need to loop to place an event listener to each class.
            let Index = 0
            while (Index < ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses.length) {
                thing = ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id
                ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].addEventListener('mousedown', PlaceDragOriginPos.bind(event, ClickHoldChangeNumberClasses[Index].id))
                Index++
            }
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', ExitPlaceDragOriginPos);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);
        
    }
    function logKey(e) {
        if (MouseState != "PressedDown") {
            MouseDragOriginX = e.clientX
            MouseDragOriginY = e.clientY
        }
        document.getElementById("MousePos").innerHTML = "Mouse position: (" + MouseDragOriginX.toString(10) + ", " + MouseDragOriginY.toString(10) + ")<br>"
        document.getElementById("DeltaDrag").innerHTML = "Delta from mouse position: (" + (e.clientX - MouseDragOriginX).toString(10) + ", " + (e.clientY - MouseDragOriginY).toString(10) + ")<br>"
        if (MouseState == "PressedDown") {
            SubFunctionVariable = [e.clientX, e.clientY]
            MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease()
        }
    }
//When the user presses down on the mouse key
    function PlaceDragOriginPos(ElementID) {
        WhichElement = ElementID
        MouseState = "PressedDown"
        //Adjust source position
            SourcePosition = parseInt(document.getElementById(WhichElement.substring((WhichElement.search(/_/) + 1), WhichElement.search(/$/))).value)
        //Cancel selection (if it didn't cancel selection, it is possible to release the mouse button WITHOUT firing the ExitPlaceDragOriginPos until the user presses and releases the mouse button
        //as it causes the user to drag selected text which could interrupt this)
            if (window.getSelection) {
                if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
                    window.getSelection().empty();
                } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
                    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
                }
            } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
                document.selection.empty();
            }
    }
//After pressing down on the mouse key and moves the cursor left or right, to adjust the number in the input.
//To use, make sure:
//-the id part of the html tag is formatted like this: NameID_NumberInputID, where NameID is any name, without any underscores.
//-the element where you want this effect on has the class "ClickHoldChangeNumber" and its id <NumberInputID> of which number input will be affected by it.
    function MouseMoveIncreaseDecrease() {
        document.getElementById(WhichElement.substring((WhichElement.search(/_/) + 1), WhichElement.search(/$/))).value = (SourcePosition + (SubFunctionVariable[0] - MouseDragOriginX)).toString(10)
    }
    function ExitPlaceDragOriginPos() {
        MouseState = "Released"
    }
</script>
```